# Odd issue with JqueryUI and Firefox, position of content is not in the dialog

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

I noticed an issue with a dialog I have installed.
I might just be tired or really just missing something.
I use jqueryUi all the time.

However in FF, the dialog when clicking "need help?" on the left hand side opens and closes on pressing escape but the content if you look at inspector is up the top of the screen and out of the visible area of the dialog?

**[Link to page](http://www.pretavoir.co.uk/emporio-armani-c-2367.html)**

Any ideas? A bit stuck on this one... unfortunately!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That is very odd. I also found that when looking at it with firebug, if I cancel the css overflow:hidden attribute of the ui-dialog class, the content automagically appears. After that, I can bring back that attribute, and the content is still there.

Not really an answer to your question, but a little bit of feedback regardless. Good luck!

Comment: Yeh that was my thoughts, pretty odd!

Comment: Turns out it was something to do with the animation! Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

try setting the div with id="dialog-modal" to have a style="display:none;".  Initially when the page loads it has the content being rendered to the bottom of the page and it's visible.  Just a shot in the dark, but hope it helps.

Comment: Woops, forgot to do that, will try it when I'm back in the office on Monday! Thanks!

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?

Comment: It had no effect, turns out it was the animation!

Comment: What was it about the animation, how did you fix it?